# How to Upload Data to Firebase Database and Retrieve it by help of date using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, forms, firebase-realtime-database

Is there anyway to upload data to Firebase and retrieve it? Using javascript which contains two text boxes and and save and retrieve/refresh button. Save button saves data to Firebase database and retrieve/refresh button takes data from Firebase Database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is way.
There are two text boxes in code 1st is to enter data and 2nd one is for to select date.
Make sure you have created firebase Account then create Firebase realtime database in test mode.

**Change the Firebase realtime database rules to**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form_container">
            <input placeholder="Enter Your Data" type="number" id="number"/>
        </div>
    
        <div id="form_container1">
            <input placeholder="Enter Todays Date" type="date" id="todaydate"/>
        </div>

        <div id="button_container">
        <button id="savedata" onclick="save()"> Save </button>
        </div>

        <div id="button_container3">
        <button id="read" onclick="get()"> Read </button>
        </div>
    </body>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.3.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    </html>
```

**index.js**

```
// Add here Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional 

// Initialize Firebase  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

            function save() 
           {
                var data = document.getElementById('number').value
                var date = document.getElementById('todaydate').value
        
                database.ref('users/' + date).set({
                data : data,
                date : date
                })
        
                alert('Saved')
        
            }
            function get() {
                var date = document.getElementById('todaydate').value
              
                var user_ref = database.ref('users/' + date)
                user_ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                  var data = snapshot.val()
                  document.getElementById('number').value = snapshot.val().data;
              
                })
              }
```